# How to create a scatter plot in pandas grouped by time of day

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to create a scatter plot using Pandas where the values are grouped by time of day and coloured/styled differently based on the day. The code snippet below will create a scatter plot of two time-series.

```
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=48, freq='H')
x = pd.Series(range(len(idx)), index=idx)
y = x
d = {'x': x, 'y': y}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.plot.scatter(x='x', y='y')
```

However, when I tried to aggregate the data in a list by time of day, I was unable to plot them as scatter:

```
df['time'] = df.index.time
df_agg= df.groupby('time').agg(list)
```

Comment: Do you want to groupby time? Meaning the values having `time` as 00:00:00 will be of one color, the values having `time` as 01:00:00 will have a different color and so on?

Comment: I was looking to group by time meaning that the x and y axis is of length time (in this case 24) and coloured by day (in this case 2 colours as 2 days).

Comment: If you groupby time, then how can you separate by day? When you are grouping by time, then the day doesn't come into play since the values are aggregated together

Comment: I was able to get the two days as so however the issue is that they should be plotted on top of each other for the two separate days -- the x and y axis should be of length 24 not 48 ```ax = plt.subplot()
for date, data in df.groupby(df.index.date):
    a = df[df.index.date == date].values
    a = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['x', 'y'])
    a.plot.scatter(x='x', y='y', ax=ax)
plt.show()```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to perform a scatter plot and keep all the data, I suggest not using `groupby`. Instead, the `hour` and `day` methods of DatetimeIndex objects provide a simple way to color by day and plot by daytime hour.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

idx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=48, freq='H')
x = pd.Series(range(len(idx)), index=idx)
y = x
# add 'hour' and 'day' columns in the dataframe
d = {'x': x, 'y': y, 'hour': idx.hour, 'day': idx.day}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
# use 'hour' as x axis to plot, and 'day' as marker color
df.plot.scatter(x='hour', y='y', c='day', colormap='rainbow')
plt.show()
```